# Check overlapping dates using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am planning to develop a cash back module in the following scenario:

There will be test cases that admin can set a cash back for one product whose date range conflicts with previously defined cashbacks on the same product.

For example:

admin set a cash back for a product P1 as (possibilities):

```
26-Dec-2016 to 29-Dec-2016 10%
25-Dec-2016 to 30-Dec-2016 10%
24-Dec-2016 to 31-Dec-2016 10%
```

How to handle the date range so that cashback date range does not overlap with other dates?

Or admin can not set a new cash back if a date range falls in previously defined cash back for a specific date range. If we can go with this then how to manage (how to check date range is falls in another one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming, Inside database you are storing the **cashback** as a row with the `CashbackStartDate` and `CashbackEndDate` as columns.

When ever setting a new date range, say `newStartDate` and `newEndDate`, first search for all the **cashbacks** with `CashbackStartDate` less than `newEndDate` and then `CashbackEndDate` grater than `newStartDate`.

This will grab all the **cashback** with the overlapping dates, for you.

Back to your question, just check if any rows are returned, if yes then .....you know what to do.

**Sample SQL code:**

```
... WHERE newStartDate < CashbackEndDate
      AND newEndDate   > CashbackStartDate;
```

*This should get you all the overlapping dates with partial and total overlap.*

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Mohd Abdul Mujid,

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Mohd Abdul Mujid,

Further, Yes I am going to store start and end date in DB for a cashback.

Also, solution that you have suggested, will it cover the following scenario:

if newStartDate if less than the savedStartDate and newEndDate is greater than savedStartDate

example: saved start and end date [25-12-2016 to 30-12-2016]
new start and end date [24-12-2016 to 31-12-2016]

Please update me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: @AtulSharma yes the above given code will work since ns(new start) 24 is `<` the ee(existing end) 30 and likewise ne 31 > ee 30. IYKWIM